# Divide results from two query by another query in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query in Metabase:

```
with l1 as (SELECT date_trunc ('day', Ticket_Escalated_At) as time_scale, count (Ticket_ID) as chat_per_day
    FROM CHAT_TICKETS where SUPPORT_QUEUE = 'transfer_investigations'
    and    date_trunc('month', TICKET_ESCALATED_AT) >  now() - interval '6' Month
    GROUP by 1)

with l2 as (SELECT date_trunc('day', created_date) as week, count(*) as TI_watchman_ticket
FROM jira_issues
WHERE issue_type NOT IN ('Transfer - General', 'TI - Advanced')
and    date_trunc('month', created_date) >  now() - interval '6' Month
and project_key  = 'TI2'
GROUP BY 1)

SELECT l1.* from l1
UNION SELECT l2.* from l2

ORDER by 1
```

and this one:

```
with hours as (SELECT date_trunc('day', ws.start_time) as date_
    ,(ifnull(sum((case when ws.shift_position = 'TI - Non-watchman' then (minutes_between(ws.end_time, ws.start_time)/60) end)),0) + ifnull(sum((case when ws.shift_position = 'TI - Watchman' then (minutes_between(ws.end_time, ws.start_time)/60) end)),0) ) as total
from chat_agents a
    join wiw_shifts ws on a.email = ws.user_email
    left join people_ops.employees h on substr(h.email,1, instr(h.email,'@revolut') - 1) = a.login
where     (seniority != 'Lead' or seniority is null)
    and    date_trunc('month', ws.start_time) >  now() - interval '6' Month
GROUP BY 1)
```

I would like to divide the output of the UNION of the first one, by the result of the second one, any ideas.

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help, so it is clear what YOU mean by "divide".

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right: First query give daily workload units, and the second query, give the daily total of hours, done by the team. So i would like to get the daily, total of work unit, divided by the total of hours.  To understand how much time is need to complete a unit